# A highly oscillatory integral

Tags: improper-integrals, oscillatory-integral

I have an integral which I am supposed to solve numerically and can find an approximated answer to it. The integral in question is

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin^2{\frac1{x}} \, \mathrm{d}x=\pi~.$$

I have check numerous sources but cannot find an analytical approach to the integral. Possibly there is a neat trick using a residual or something which I cannot see, but I am out of luck.

If someone have noticed a way to find an exact answer, I would definitely appreciate it.

Comment: Looks like $$2\int_0^\infty\sin^2 y\frac{dy}{y^2}.$$

Comment: I am slightly hesitant, as the change of variables is not correct, what I can note. On the other side, your integral gives the answer $\sqrt{\pi}$, which also makes the idea not in the correct direction. I do appreciate the effort :)

Comment: Another idea, which came into my mind, was to possibly use a Fourier transform, will investigate this further.

Comment: No, my change of variables is correct, and the answer is $\pi$, not $\sqrt\pi$.

Comment: You are definitely right, my bad! Still, I do not know how to continue with this integral.

Comment: It's pretty much the same as $$2\int_0^\infty\sin y\frac{dy}y.$$

Comment: That is true. What I can see is that one can use Feynman's trick or trying to see that this integral converges, but no analytical answer is here. You clarified for me, kudos @LordSharktheUnknown.